# Morphia : Accepting single value as array, for a field in morphia entity

Tags: java, json, serialization, morphia

Lets say I have class

```
@Entity
class MyCollectionEntity {

    @Property("sample_field")
    private List<String> sampleField;
}
```

Here morphia is able to save the json documents where the sampleField key has value like

```
{
 "sample_field":["field1", "field2"]
}
```

But I need this entity to map the values which are not in list and just a string too like

```
{
"sample_field": "field1"
}
```

in the same sampleField class as List. How can I achieve this when the key may take value as an array of objects as well as sometimes just the object ?
This will be similar to the feature provided in Jackson `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY`
I am using `org.mongodb.morphia v1.3.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Morphia does not support that kind of serialization.  1.3.2 is *super* old so i'm trying to remember the details.  I think it can *read* such values (but that's not a promise) but will write out a `List` as an array in the documents.